# ActiveMQ : queue VS temporaryQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ in order to communicate between servers.

Every server holds one queue in order to send messages and temporaryQueue per each thread in order to receive messages.

When i am using about ~>32 threads i am receiving

```
 Cannot publish to a deleted Destination: temp-queue: xxx
```

After a while.

When i change from temporaryQueue to "regular" queue everything works perfectly.

```
(session.createQueue(...) instead of session.createTemporaryQueue())
```

Why am i getting this error ?

Does it cost more me when i use "regular" queue ?

Comment: It's unclear why you need to use temp queues in the first place.

Comment: http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

Answer (score 1):

So implementing request reply using non temporary queues you need some way to correlate the response to a request. You can use the correlation-id header. Since you are not really supposed to create request-unique regular queues, but a fixed set of queues. Like ORDER.CONFIRMATION.RESPONSE or similar. So, it's less costly to use regular queues - IF you reuse them.

To read messages using multiple threads from a common response queue - use a message selector to select JMSCorrelationID header for your particular answer.

However you should be able to use temp queues as well. Your problem is likely some kind of usage issue - but the information provided does not give any clues as it reveals no implementation or analysis.

Comment: From the ActiveMQ specification :  The best way to implement request-response over JMS is to create a temporary queue and consumer per client on startup, set JMSReplyTo property on each message to the temporary queue and then use a correlationID on each message to correlate request messages to response messages. This avoids the overhead of creating and closing a consumer for each request (which is expensive). It also means you can share the same producer & consumer across many threads if you want (or pool them maybe).

Comment: I do it to avoid many Threads : But from some reason it causing messaging failures.